# Will P6SPY logging work with IBM Websphere 7 App Server?

Tags: logging, websphere, websphere-7, p6spy

I have setup P6Spy with Tomcat successfully. Can anyone tell me How to configure P6spy for IBM WebSphere 7? Is there any way?? The reason I posted here is because it isreally difficult finding any solution.

**Threads :**

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/p6spy-developers/B_58WM7fslU/KURX3TooLyQJ;context-place=forum/p6spy-developers
2. https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/issues/186
3. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013779511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking for from p6spy is jdbc statement tracing, you can obtain that sort of information without installing any additional software in WebSphere App Server, just turn on JDBC trace  as outlined in [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.soafep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rtrb_jdbccomp.html).  If you decide to invest the time to try to get p6spy working, you may want to do so on a newer version of WAS, v7 will reach end of service in April 2018 (5 months).

Comment: Companys test servers are still running on WAS 5 or something. Cant do anything about. Thanks for the JDBC Trace thing.